# can't install selenium in eclipse with maven 'module not accessible'

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to install selenium 4 librery in eclipse with maven in an existing modular project but ,I have an error after putting selenium-java dependency
all errors are like this:

`The type org.openqa.selenium.By is not accessible`
even after adding them in the module info file
some selenium modules has this errors :
`org.openqa.selenium.chrome cannot be resolved to a module`
I have this problem just with selenium dependency other libs are working fine .
i tried to install it manually but i got same errors .
[this is project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2a2m.png)

Comment: Did you try maven clean and then build?

Comment: yes, it doen't work

Answer (score 0):

Try following steps:

-Either keep only selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar as an external JAR
-keep only selenium-java-3.141.59
-Clean your project and update maven

You can update these versuon through maven.

Comment: i did it but it doesn't work i got `error can't be resolved as module` i searched why i found that is because i have a modular project and selinium 3.141.59 is not modular lib so they are not compatible .